# "If he were" or "if he had been"

Tags: grammar

> 1.if **he were** my brother, I would have helped him.
>
> 2.if **he had been** my brother, I would have helped him.

Are both sentences correct? If so, then how?

I think it's a third conditional. unreal past condition-unreal past result. but for that we should use had been not "were". I saw first one in my textbook.

Answer (score 1):

*Were* is used in the Type-2 conditional sentences in the *If-clauses* and usually combines with the conditional present tense (would+ root verb) in the *principal clauses*. So, we can write: "If he **were** my brother, I **would help** him." Here, *were* implies an unreal hypothetical situation of "he being my brother" irrespective of any given time (which never occurred nor possible).

In the Type-3 conditional sentences, the past perfect form of the verb (had+past participle form of the verb) is used in the *If-clause*, while the *principal clause* takes the *conditional perfect* tense form. Thus, it is correct to write: "If he **had been** my brother, I **would have helped** him." This is also the same hypothetical situation that *seemed possible* in the past. This expresses a sense of regret.

Answer (score 0):

**Number 2**.

This is an example of the third conditional:-

"The third conditional is used for situations that didn’t happen in the past and their imaginary results"

http://englishxp.co.uk/grammar/conditionals/

What textbook are you using?

Comment: it's in my english tuition textbook.

Comment: What's the name of the book?

Comment: It is kind of a local grammar book published by my english language teacher.